# Cucumber BDD, call gRPC

Tags: apache-camel, grpc, bdd, citrus-framework

I am new to BDD, want to call gRPC.

gRPC is working without BDD by following way

command: 
./grpcurl -vv -proto functionsNservices_file_java.proto -plaintext localhost:8080 service_in_proto.func

output: exactly what I need

Where
functionsNservices_file_java.proto is a java file 
localhost:8080 is deamon 
service_in_proto.func is defined in functionsNservices_file_java.proto file

**Problem:** 
is how can i call gRPC using BDD script. as BDD supports camel and camel supports gRPC.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use Apache Camel for the wiring?

Comment: because, I am working on BDD script.  Yaks.. 
and yaks supports apache camel.. yaks is very limited in functionality i dont have other option